# Changing dataframe values with a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, global-variables

My problem is that i want to use a function to change a random value to NA in a global data frame.

df is a dataframe with 230 rows and 2 columns.

abstract code:

```
emptychange<- function(x){
  placenumber <- round(runif(1,min= min(1),max=max(nrow(x))))
  x[placenumber,2] <<- NA
}

emptychange(df)
```

The Error is:"Error in x[placenumber, 2] <<- NA : object 'x' not found".

I think the mistake is, that r searches for the global variable 'x' and doesn't use the function x-value (in this case df). How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. The problem was this: `<<- NA` Double arrows are used when you want to assign a value to an object outside the function. In you case, your `x` is inside the function.

```
df1 <-data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10)

emptychange<- function(x){
  placenumber <- round(runif(1,min= min(1),max=max(nrow(x))))
  x[placenumber,2] <- NA
  return(x)
}

emptychange(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but i can't really change a global data frame with a function right? I have to write `df1<-emptychange(df1)`

Comment: You can assign data to the global environment inside a function. For example, if you added `df2 <<-x` at the end of the function, you would create a `df2` object in the global environment. However, in your case, the `x` in your function is inside the function. For what you want to do, it is good practice to do `df1<-emptychange(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

f you want this to be done at the console,  you can just use `sample`-ing from the row count inside the `[<-` function:

```
> df1 <-data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10)
> df1[sample(nrow(df1), 1) , 2] <- NA
> df1
   x  y
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  1  4
5  1  5
6  1 NA
7  1  7
8  1  8
9  1  9
10 1 10
```

If you want to destructively change the dataframe argument given to a function you should instead assign the value which is returned back to the original name:

```
>  randNA.secCol <- function(df) {df[sample(nrow(df), 1) , 2] <- NA; df}
> df1 <-data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10)
> df1 <- randNA.secCol(df1)
```

Best practice in R is avoidance of the use of the `<<-` function.